File list and monitor
I recently was given a take home assignment for a job interview. The task was specified like so:
Create a command-line program that accepts an optional argument: “-d path”. If the
path is not supplied, it defaults to “~/inbox/”. If the path does not exist, it should be
created. We refer to this path as “INBOX” in the rest of the document.

Program workflow:
1. Scan the folder recursively and print to stdout all the files found and their last
modification date in the following format: “[Date Time] PATH”, where PATH is a
relative path to INBOX.
2. Start monitoring INBOX for file changes. When an event occurs, print it to stdout
in the following format: “[EVENT] PATH”, where EVENT is one of the following
[NEW, MOD, DEL].
3. Continue monitoring until the user inputs Ctrl-C.
4. Once Ctrl-C is detected, print to stdout the contents of INBOX again in the same
format, without rescanning or any other FS operations.

Bonus points for:
1. Using tokio
2. Using structured error handling
3. Not using mutexes
4. Having separation of concerns

Furthermore, this was supposed to be done in Rust and I was told that I could use external libraries. This was the code that I submitted:
use notify::{self, recommended_watcher, Event, EventKind, RecursiveMode, Watcher};
use tokio::{self, signal, sync::mpsc, task::JoinHandle};
use time::{OffsetDateTime, format_description};
use clap::{self, Parser};
use fxhash::FxHashMap as HashMap;
use walkdir::WalkDir;
use shellexpand;
use std::time::SystemTime;
use std::path::{Path, PathBuf};
use std::fmt::{Display, self};
use std::fs;
use std::io;

// If terminal printing gets any more complicated,
// it'd probably be better to use an external crate.
struct TermMode {}

impl TermMode {
    pub const Black: &str = "\x1b[30m";
    pub const Red: &str = "\x1b[31m";
    pub const Green: &str = "\x1b[32m";
    pub const Yellow: &str = "\x1b[33m";
    pub const Bold: &str = "\x1b[1m";
    pub const Reset: &str = "\x1b[0m";
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Inbox {
    path: PathBuf,

    // Use a HashMap for more efficient insert and delete operations.
    // HashMap also makes it so we don't get duplicate entries.
    // This messes up ordering but I think it's ok.
    files: HashMap<PathBuf, SystemTime>,
}

const TIME_FORMAT: &str = "[year]-[month]-[day] [hour]:[minute]:[second]";

impl Display for Inbox {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        if self.files.len() == 0 {
            write!(f, "{} is empty", self.path.display())
        } else {
            writeln!(f, "Contents of {}", self.path.display());

            for (i, (path, last_modified)) in self.files.iter().enumerate() {
                let datetime: OffsetDateTime = (*last_modified).into();
                let date_str = match format_description::parse(TIME_FORMAT) {
                    Ok(format) => datetime.format(&format).unwrap_or("ERROR".to_string()),
                    _ => "ERROR".to_string()
                };

                write!(f, "[{}] {}", date_str, path.display());

                if i < self.files.len() - 1 {
                    write!(f, "\n");
                }
            }

            Ok(())
        }
    }
}

impl Inbox {
    fn new(dir: &Path) -> io::Result<Self> {
        let mut files = HashMap::default();

        for entry in WalkDir::new(dir).into_iter().filter_map(Result::ok) {
            let path = entry.path();

            let rel_path = match path.strip_prefix(dir) {
                Ok(p) => p.to_owned(),
                _ => path.to_owned(),
            };

            let md = fs::metadata(&path)?;
            let last_modified = md.modified()?;

            // Don't print "." which with the prefix stripped looks empty.
            if rel_path.components().next().is_some() {
                files.insert(rel_path, last_modified);
            }
        }

        let canon_path = match dir.canonicalize() {
            Ok(p) => p,
            _ => dir.to_owned(),
        };

        Ok(Inbox {
            path: canon_path,
            files: files,
        })
    }

    fn log(&self, event: &Event) {
        for path in &event.paths {
            let rel_path = match path.strip_prefix(&self.path) {
                Ok(p) => p.to_owned(),
                _ => path.to_owned(),
            };

            let (kind_str, color) = match &event.kind {
                EventKind::Create(_) => ("NEW", TermMode::Green),
                EventKind::Modify(_) => ("MOD", TermMode::Yellow),
                EventKind::Remove(_) => ("DEL", TermMode::Red),
                _ => ("UNKNOWN", TermMode::Black),
            };

            println!(
                "[{}{}{}{}] {}",
                TermMode::Bold,
                color,
                kind_str,
                TermMode::Reset,
                rel_path.display()
            );
        }
    }

    fn handle(&mut self, event: &Event) {
        let event_time = SystemTime::now();

        for path in &event.paths {
            let rel_path = match path.strip_prefix(&self.path) {
                Ok(p) => p.to_owned(),
                _ => path.to_owned(),
            };

            // We still don't care about operations to ".".
            if rel_path.components().next().is_none() {
                continue;
            }

            match &event.kind {
                EventKind::Create(_) => {
                    self.files.insert(rel_path, event_time.clone());
                },
                EventKind::Modify(_) => {
                    self.files
                        .iter_mut()
                        .for_each(|(p, t)| {
                            if p == &rel_path {
                                *t = event_time.clone();
                            }
                        });
                },
                EventKind::Remove(_) => {
                    self.files.remove(&rel_path);
                },
                _ => {},
            }
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Parser)]
pub struct Args {
    #[arg(short = 'd', default_value = "~/inbox")]
    path: String,
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let args = Args::parse();

    let watcher_task: JoinHandle<notify::Result<()>> = tokio::spawn(async move {
        let dir_ = shellexpand::tilde(&args.path).into_owned();
        let dir = Path::new(&dir_);

        let canon_dir = match dir.canonicalize() {
            Ok(p) => p,
            _ => dir.to_owned(),
        };

        if !canon_dir.exists() {
            fs::create_dir_all(&canon_dir)
                .expect(format!("Could not create inbox at {}", canon_dir.display()).as_str());
        }

        let mut inbox = Inbox::new(&canon_dir)?;
        println!("{}", inbox);

        let (mut tx, mut rx) = mpsc::channel::<notify::Result<Event>>(100);

        // In the watcher, synchronously send the event on the receive channel.
        let mut watcher = recommended_watcher(move |res| {
            tx.blocking_send(res).expect("Could not send fs event to tokio channel");
        })?;

        watcher.watch(&canon_dir, RecursiveMode::Recursive)?;

        loop {
            tokio::select! {
                Ok(_) = signal::ctrl_c() => {
                    println!("{}", inbox);
                    break;
                },
                Some(res) = rx.recv() => {
                    match res {
                        Ok(event) => {
                            inbox.log(&event);
                            inbox.handle(&event);
                        },
                        Err(err) => eprintln!("Error receiving fs event: {}", err),
                    };
                },
            }
        }

        Ok(())
    });
    
    match watcher_task.await {
        Ok(_) => {},
        Err(err) => {
            eprintln!("Error awaiting fs watch task to finish: {}", err);
        },
    }
}

The code works to specification; however, after submitting this I was rejected for the job without explanation and my request for feedback was ghosted.
When trying to figure out why I was rejected, I realized that I had RUSTFLAGS="-Awarnings" in my bashrc so I'm aware that there are some warnings in my submission (though nothing serious imo).
Other than that, I'm not sure what I could've done to improve my submission.
How well does my solution match the prompt?
Here is my Cargo.toml:
[package]
name = "challenge"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
clap = {version = "4.5.21", features = ["derive"]}
fxhash = "0.2.1"
notify = "7.0.0"
shellexpand = "3.1.0"
time = {version = "0.3.36", features = ["formatting"]}
tokio = {version = "1.41.1", features = ["full"]}
walkdir = "2.5.0"


Welcome to Code Review! I changed the title so that it describes what the code does per site goals: "State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it.". Feel free to [edit] and give it a different title if there is something more appropriate. Also - it may be helpful for reviewers if the "use statements" were included.

Gotcha, thanks. I've added the use statements to the code listing

There are many warnings (10 from cargo build, 18 from clippy) - that might be a problem. Please rephrase your question to remove the "why did a random recruiter reject me" stance - chances are that this code itself wasn't related to your rejection at all. I'll try to write an answer and point out what looks surprising for me, but this is in reasonably good shape IMO. Please post your Cargo.toml file too - there are several external deps with non-default feature flags.

I've added the Cargo.toml to the post. I'm not sure how to rephrase the question though. I posted this basically because I wanted to sanity check that I can actually program and was very confused as to the abrupt rejection. I agree with you that it was probably not fully related to the code but I wanted to see what some other people thought.

Compiler & lint warnings
You already noticed this yourself, but I'd still mention this. cargo build
emits whopping 11 warnings, and cargo clippy 18 (some are overlapping). That's
really too much for 200 LOC.
Some of those warnings are style-ish (upper case for constants or unnecessary mut), but some other are rather important:
warning: unused `Result` that must be used
  --> src/main.rs:44:13
   |
44 |             writeln!(f, "Contents of {}", self.path.display());
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: this `Result` may be an `Err` variant, which should be handled
   = note: `#[warn(unused_must_use)]` on by default
   = note: this warning originates in the macro `writeln` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

warning: unused `Result` that must be used
  --> src/main.rs:53:17
   |
53 |                 write!(f, "[{}] {}", date_str, path.display());
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: this `Result` may be an `Err` variant, which should be handled
   = note: this warning originates in the macro `write` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

warning: unused `Result` that must be used
  --> src/main.rs:56:21
   |
56 |                     write!(f, "\n");
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: this `Result` may be an `Err` variant, which should be handled
   = note: this warning originates in the macro `write` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

All in all, please make it a habit to cargo check && cargo clippy before commiting/sharing a snippet.
Surprising use of struct
TermMode is never constructed and is used solely to define a group of constants. This is quite unusual: rust has mod specifically for that.
Let's rewrite that as
mod term_mode {
    pub const BLACK: &str = "\x1b[30m";
    pub const RED: &str = "\x1b[31m";
    pub const GREEN: &str = "\x1b[32m";
    pub const YELLOW: &str = "\x1b[33m";
    pub const BOLD: &str = "\x1b[1m";
    pub const RESET: &str = "\x1b[0m";
}

Error handling
As pointed out by cargo check, you discard several results of writeln! and write!. Just add ? after them to fail early.
However, this isn't the primary issue with error handling here. As currently written,
the program will silently exit on permissions issue:
$ mkdir -m 700 /tmp/foo
mkdir: created directory '/tmp/foo'
$ touch -m 600 /tmp/foo/a.py
$ sudo chown -R root:root /tmp/foo
$ cargo run -- -d /tmp/foo
[...]
    Finished `dev` profile [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.04s
     Running `target/debug/temp -d /tmp/foo`
/tmp/foo is empty

I didn't send ^C, the program silently exited with status code 0. And the folder isn't empty. Oops...
Now there are many ways to set "unexpected" permissions resulting in incorrect program behavior.
OTOH, this is too much in my opinion:
let date_str = match format_description::parse(TIME_FORMAT) {
    Ok(format) => datetime.format(&format).unwrap_or("ERROR".to_string()),
    _ => "ERROR".to_string()
};

Failure to parse a hardcoded format deserves a hard crash (panic), it shouldn't generate ERROR lines.
Conformance
Your problem explicitly asked to print one of {NEW, MOD, DEL} events. However, simply testing your sample with touch, I see a bunch of UNKNOWN events printed along. I think it'd be better to silence them instead of printing.
let (kind_str, color) = match &event.kind {
    EventKind::Create(_) => ("NEW", term_mode::GREEN),
    EventKind::Modify(_) => ("MOD", term_mode::YELLOW),
    EventKind::Remove(_) => ("DEL", term_mode::RED),
    _ => {continue;},
};

Also:

Scan the folder recursively and print to stdout all the files

You, however, print directories as well. That might be fine, but doesn't match the requirements as written (yes, you could argue directories are files on Linux, but I don't think it's the intended interpretation - anyway, a comment explaining your choice would remove such questions entirely).
Code duplication
I see this repeated twice (or even three times, counting similar piece in Inbox::new):
let rel_path = match path.strip_prefix(&self.path) {
    Ok(p) => p.to_owned(),
    _ => path.to_owned(),
};

This might be a separate method.
Efficiency
This:
self.files
    .iter_mut()
    .for_each(|(p, t)| {
        if p == &rel_path {
            *t = event_time.clone();
        }
    });

looks really scary. You don't need to iterate over the whole map to update a value:
self.files.entry(rel_path).and_modify(|t| *t = event_time);

You can also just set a value straight ahead, since Modify event shouldn't be issued for a non-existent file, assuming that events are guaranteed to arrive in order (I don't know whether it's true - if not, you've got more problems).
Comments
Not sure what you meant by this, but files in a filesystem are not ordered anyway,
directory traversal order is undefined.
    // Use a HashMap for more efficient insert and delete operations.
    // HashMap also makes it so we don't get duplicate entries.
    // This messes up ordering but I think it's ok.
    files: HashMap<PathBuf, SystemTime>,

Program structure
Your main is doing too much: all the directory perturbations belong to a separate helper function, it must be testable. That part also needn't be in watcher_task - it would be more reasonable to do that preparatory work right in main body instead, before the task is launched.
Standard library
It's definitely good to use purpose-built solutions when they are available. However, it doesn't mean introducing unneeded dependencies. Why fxhash::FxHashMap? If there was some problem using the std collection, please add a comment to mention that.

Thank you for the review. This is very helpful feedback. I definitely didn't think about permissions issues!
